# Show all the steps to convert a given string to another (anagrams)

Tags: java

Interview Question
Given two input strings, You can swap only two consecutive elements in a string. You have to show all steps to convert a string into another string (both strings will be **anagrams** of each other). E.g. GUM to MUG

GUM 
GMU 
MGU 
MUG

Code for this is as shown below.

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        char a[] = "GUM".toCharArray();
        char b[] = "MUG".toCharArray();
        char temp;
        int n = b.length;
        int j, i = 0;
        while(n > i) {
            j = i;
            System.out.println(a);
            while(a[j] != b[i]) {
                j++;
            }
            while(j > i) {
                temp = a[j];
                a[j] = a[j-1];
                a[j-1] = temp;
                System.out.println(a);
                j--;
            }
            i++;
        }
    }
}
```

Output is as follows.

```
GUM
GMU
MGU
MGU
MUG
MUG
```

Can somebody help me to remove the duplicate steps/repeated steps in the above code? 
Or **any other better way to do this?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing correctly .Just remove the

```
System.out.println(a);
```

Before  `while(a[j] != b[i])`

And add the same before top while loop. Reason for the duplicate - you already displaying the change in last while loop.

```
char a[] = "GUM".toCharArray();
        char b[] = "MUG".toCharArray();
        char temp;
        int n = b.length;
        int j, i = 0;

        System.out.println(a);
        while (n > i) {
            j = i;
            while (a[j] != b[i]) {
                j++;
            }
            while (j > i) {
                temp = a[j];
                a[j] = a[j - 1];
                a[j - 1] = temp;
                System.out.println(a);
                j--;
            }
            i++;
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for posting this too.

Comment: That doesn't look correct. What if the two strings are ABBCD" and "DCBBA"?

Comment: @SpiderPig - It is working for that input too and it is not having any duplicate...